# Is there a TextWriter interface to the System.Diagnostics.Debug class, for use with Console.SetOut?

Tags: c#, console-application, stdout, output-window

Is there anything built-in that can redirect Console.WriteLine calls to System.Diagnostic.Debug-calls?

I was hoping for something like this:

```
public static void CallNastyConsoleWriteLineUsingFunction() {
    Console.WriteLine(GetImportantInformation());
}

[...]

var writer = DebugTextWriter();
TextWriter stdout = Console.Out;
try
{
    Console.SetOut(writer);
    CallNastyConsoleWriteLineUsingFunction();
}
finally
{
    Console.SetOut(stdout);
}
```

Or maybe even:

```
using(new ConsoleToDebugRedirector())
{
    CallNastyConsoleWriteLineUsingFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (new ConsoleRedirect<DebugTextWriter>())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing testing...");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Testing testing 2...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ConsoleRedirect<T> : IDisposable
    where T : TextWriter, new()
{
    private readonly TextWriter _tmpTextWriter;

    public ConsoleRedirect()
    {
        _tmpTextWriter = Console.Out;
        Console.SetOut(new T());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.SetOut(_tmpTextWriter);
    }
}

public class DebugTextWriter : TextWriter
{
    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(object value)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string format, params object[] arg)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(format, arg);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

It will redirect all `Console.WriteLine` calls to `Debug.WriteLine` while inside the `using` statement. It is pretty cumbersome to override all the write methods of the `TextWriter`, but you could probably use the wrapper in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779746/is-there-a-textwriter-interface-to-the-system-diagnostics-debug-class)

Answer (score 2):

You can do the reverse. Use standard Debug/Trace calls and add a [ConsoleTraceListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to your configuration. The net effect should be the same with standard coding/behavior.

Comment: I'm calling a DLL that calls Console.WriteLine.